# How to add user defined constraints on a node/relationship in Neo4j using Java API

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-java-api, neo4j-bolt

Consider I have a node having Label `L1` in **Neo4j** database. I need to put a constraint on all nodes having label `L1` such that there shall be no outgoing edge from these nodes. So whenever user tries to add an outgoing edge from these nodes, a constraint violation occurs. Is it possible to add user defined constraints on nodes and relationships?

If yes, how can I put such constraint(s) on nodes/relationships using **Neo4j** Java API's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Neo4j constraints documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-prop-exist-rels) there is no way to do this.

I think you should delegate this type of responsibility to the application layer. Alternatively, you can try achieve your goal writing your own [user defined procedure](https://neo4j.com/developer/procedures-functions/).

Comment: If it cannot be done then what are the usages of the enums ConstraintType.NODE_PROPERTY_EXISTENCE and ConstraintType.RELATIONSHIP_PROPERTY_EXISTENCE?

Comment: [NODE_PROPERTY_EXISTENCE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-prop-exist-nodes): ensures that all nodes with a certain label have a certain property. 

[RELATIONSHIP_PROPERTY_EXISTENCE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-prop-exist-rels): makes sure that all relationships with a certain type have a certain property.

@SuvamKumarDas

Comment: Can these two enums be somehow used to create constraints which satisfy properties on node and relationships?

Comment: @SuvamKumarDas Sorry, I did not understand. Are you talking about ensure that a given node has an specified property?

Comment: Not exactly. If RELATIONSHIP_PROPERTY_EXISTENCE makes sure that all relationships with a certain type have a certain property, then can it be used to create a constraint? E.g. can I use RELATIONSHIP_PROPERTY_EXISTENCE to ensure that a particular type of relation will only exist between nodes of a particular label say L1 and L2 and not between nodes of other labels?

Comment: @SuvamKumarDas No, because labels are not properties of relationships.

Comment: @SuvamKumarDas a relationship has a start node, an end node, a type and, optionally, properties. These constraints are relative to relationship and node *properties* only.

Comment: Hi @SuvamKumarDas if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.